# Using JMX Exporter as javaagent for a sample java application

Tags: java, prometheus, prometheus-java

I am trying to get the JVM metrics of an existing java application, by using the JMX exporter as an agent. While trying to get the application up i am getting the below error. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

### config.yaml

```
startDelaySeconds: 0
ssl: false
lowercaseOutputName: true
lowercaseOutputLabelNames: true
rules:
  -pattern: ".*"
```

> `java  -javaagent:./jmx_prometheus_javaagent-0.17.0.jar=13579:./config.yaml -jar sample-app.jar`
> Error:

---

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
> Method)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
> at java.instrument/sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.loadClassAndStartAgent(InstrumentationImpl.java:513)
> at java.instrument/sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.loadClassAndCallPremain(InstrumentationImpl.java:525)
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.util.LinkedHashMap
> cannot be cast to class java.util.List (java.util.LinkedHashMap and
> java.util.List are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
> at io.prometheus.jmx.JmxCollector.loadConfig(JmxCollector.java:211)
> at io.prometheus.jmx.JmxCollector.(JmxCollector.java:91)
> at io.prometheus.jmx.JavaAgent.premain(JavaAgent.java:29)
> ... 6 more
> *** java.lang.instrument ASSERTION FAILED ***: "result" with message agent load/premain call failed at
> ./src/java.instrument/share/native/libinstrument/JPLISAgent.c line:
> 422 FATAL ERROR in native method: processing of -javaagent failed,
> processJavaStart failed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing a space after the `-` in your config.
It should be `- pattern: ".*"`, not `-pattern: ".*"`.